# How to change columns width dynamically in a grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using CSS grid, and I have 3 columns whose total width is 100%.

There's also a button, and clicking on it shows or hides the third column.

I want that as soon as the third column is hidden, the width of the second column will extend to the end of the screen, meaning, it should also occupy the space left by the third column.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("right");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.leftNav {
  background-color: red;
}

.center {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rightNav {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftNav">left nav</div>
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div id="right" class="rightNav">right nav</div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. I've commented the changes.

```js
function toggleRightNav() {
  var rightNav = document.getElementById("right");
  var container = document.querySelector(".container");

  if (rightNav.style.display === "none") {
    rightNav.style.display = "block";
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "1fr 3fr 1fr"; // revert to original layout
  } else {
    rightNav.style.display = "none";
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "1fr 4fr"; // expand the center column
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr; /* adjusted fraction to control the width */
}

.leftNav {
  background-color: red;
}

.center {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rightNav {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftNav">left nav</div>
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div id="right" class="rightNav">right nav</div>
</div>

<button onclick="toggleRightNav()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding the button, toggle a class on the container then hide it using CSS and at the same time change the grid structure

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelector(".container");
  x.classList.toggle('hide')
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.leftNav {
  background-color: red;
}

.center {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rightNav {
  background-color: green;
}



.container.hide .rightNav {
  display: none; /* hide the right nav */
}
.container.hide .center {
  grid-column: span 2; /* take 2 columns */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftNav">left nav</div>
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="rightNav">right nav</div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```